# application/pdf pisa __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mime type'

Tags: django, python-2.7, httpresponse, pisa, xhtml2pdf

this is the code:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
     template = get_template(template_src)
     context = Context(context_dict)
     html  = template.render(context)
     result = StringIO.StringIO()
     pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
     if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

I use django 1.7 and the error is

**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/amministrazione/ddts/stampa/1/
Django Version:     1.7.7
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:

**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'

Exception Location:     /home/stefano/.virtualenvs/company2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py in **init**, line 318
Python Executable:  /home/stefano/.virtualenvs/company2/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6

Answer (score 15):

Replace:

```
return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
```

with

```
return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
```

I had this problem too, and this change helped.